# How to run list of testng xml file dynamically from command line input through maven?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, testng

How to run list of testng xml file dynamically from command line input through Maven?

I have list of TestNG XML, which are listed under  for sequential execution through Maven(POM.xml)

Here i would like to run the TestNG Xml file based on the command line input.
lets me explain it with below example,

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                 <suiteXmlFiles>
                      <suiteXmlFile>TestNG1.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                      <suiteXmlFile>TestNG2.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                      <suiteXmlFile>TestNG3.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                 </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have 3 testNG XML files. I have two conditions to execute.
1. If i pass the command line input as TestNG2.xml, it should execute the TestNG2.xml alone. Not the other two get executed.

1. If i pass the parameter as 'all' then it should execute all the three files one by one.

I tried out with various methods but none of them worked.

So help me on this. Thanks in advance.....

Comment: HI @Saran, I have also similar requirement, please post the answer if you already solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can create two different profiles which contain the maven-surefire-plugin configuration with the appropriate testng files. The appropriate profile can be activated via -Pprofile on command line.

Comment: Yup, that's how I would do it. Not super practical, but that's the Maven way.